# PCF8547 Wire.write explanations

Tags: esp8266, pins, code-optimization

I am using an [ESP8266-12E](https://www.espressif.com/en/products/hardware/esp8266ex/resources) with a PCF8547. 
I have managed to turn on and turn off LEDs using these two things.
I am using these three commands to do it.

```
 Wire.begin(SDA_PIN,CLK_PIN);
 Wire.beginTransmission(0x20);
 Wire.write(~((uint8_t)1<<cnt));
 Wire.endTransmission();
```

The problem I am facing here is: I am using 4 LEDs and I am only able to turn on one LED at a time. When I turn on another, all the LEDs turn off - in short, the LEDs or the PCF8547 do not preserve the state.

I want to toggle on the LEDs without disturbing the other's state.
How can I do it?
I think, I need more knowledge about the write function, don't I?

**Update:**

I have already connected A0, A1, A2 to ground. This is the function I use now to toggle the LEDs.

```
void enlight(int cnt)
{ 
  if (cnt == 1) 
    value = value | 1<<cnt; 
    if (cnt == 2) 
      value = value | 2<<cnt; 
    if (cnt == 3) 
      value = value | 3<<cnt; 
    if (cnt == 4) 
      value = value | 4<<cnt; 
    value = ~value; 
    Wire.begin(SDA_PIN,CLK_PIN); 
    Wire.beginTransmission(0x20); Wire.write(value);      
    Wire.endTransmission(); 
  }
```

but when I turn off/on any other LEDs they also toggle, which I don't want.

[image: My Circuit Image]

Comment: Please add circuit description. How have you connected the LEDs? With to low resistors the LEDs will draw to much current. Check the numbers!

Comment: Forwarded from the user [Pete](http://arduino.stackexchange.com/users/28109/pete): Aren't the addresses of the LED's (or devices) given in the datasheet?

Comment: @MikaelPatel : i will add the circuit image that is not an issue. 
what i want to achieve is just like we send HIGH and LOW signals to GPIO pins of ESP8266-12e and turn off/on the led connected to that GPIO ,  the same i want to do with PCF8547.  i want to know technique to access the address or some identification to the I/O pins of PCF8547 so that only one led at a time i can turn on/off without affecting other pins  .

Comment: Just remember the value you sent last time, and modify only the bits you want to change. Google will tell you how to change a single bit in C (or C++).

Comment: This might be of some help; https://github.com/mikaelpatel/Cosa/blob/master/libraries/PCF8574/PCF8574.hh

Comment: @MikaelPatel : The library from which you have provided the link , does not support ESP8266-12E.

Comment: The library/code was to expire you on how to write this type of code. Cosa is a totally different approach and more advanced programming of the Arduino. https://github.com/mikaelpatel/Cosa

Comment: @MikaelPatel : I appreciate the help , but the type of functions and their working in Cosa is not there for Esp8266 . Please guide me more if possible.

Comment: Thanks for your edit - it's much clearer. I've added code to my answer showing you how to modify one light at a time - you have to remember the value of all the other lights.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

(I haven't used this library, but this looks like a general C(++) question...)

The important part of what you're doing is this:

```
Wire.write(~((uint8_t)1<<cnt));
```

Let's break it down.

It calculates a value by taking the number `1` and shifting it left `cnt` times. Then it takes the complement of that number - changes 0s to 1s and 1s to 0s.  This number is sent to Wire.write() and lights up light number `cnt`.

Example: Let's say you start with `cnt==2`, to light LED 2.  It will shift the number `1` left by two digits, giving you the binary number `00000100`.  Then it will invert this, giving you `11111011`.  This is given to Wire.write().

We can see from this that to light an LED, we need to put a '0' in the right place.

How can you make several numbers light up?  We need to put several zeros in, at the right places.

Here's an example of how you might like to do this - which isn't the prettiest code but I hope it shows you what's going on.

```
// How we would like the LEDs to appear
boolean led0 = true;    // LED 0 ON
boolean led1 = false;   // LED 1 OFF
boolean led2 = true;    // LED 2 ON
boolean led3 = false;   // LED 3 OFF

// Start with all LEDs off
uint8_t value = 0;

// Put a 1 in place for each LED we want to be ON
// The | symbol means "logical OR" (Google it)
if (led0) value = value | 1<<0;
if (led1) value = value | 1<<0;
if (led2) value = value | 2<<0;
if (led3) value = value | 3<<0;

// Invert this value
value = ~value;

// Write it to Wire
Wire.begin(SDA_PIN,CLK_PIN);
Wire.beginTransmission(0x20);
Wire.write(value);
Wire.endTransmission();
```

Since it appears you have to send values for all the lights every time, you need to remember the value you sent last time, and modify only the bits you want to change.  Here's a way you can do that:

```
void setLight(int lightNum, boolean lightOn) {
  // Remember the last state of the lights.
  // Start with all lights OFF.
  static uint8_t lightsOn = 0;

  // We only have four lights (0-3).  Only respond for lights
  // we we have.
  if (lightNum<4) {
    // Get a bitmask with a single 1 in the right
    // position for this light
    uint8_t position = 1<<lightNum;

    // Clear (to 0) that bit in the state
    lightsOn &= ~position;

    // Set (to 1) the bit if we want the light on
    if(lightOn) lightsOn |= position;

    // Write out the value of all lights
    Wire.begin(SDA_PIN,CLK_PIN);
    Wire.beginTransmission(0x20);
    Wire.write(~lightsOn);
    Wire.endTransmission();
  }
}
```

Call it with something like

```
setLight(0, true);    // Switch the first light ON
setLight(3, true);    // Switch the fourth light ON (first stays on)
setLight(0, false);   // Switch the first light OFF (fourth stays on)
```

Comment: totally explainable. i got how it works now. 
  but i am not be able to analyse what address does the pins have. 
  the code you have provided toggles all the other leds too. 
  is it possible to get the addresses of the pins on PCF8547 so that the actual led is toggled by us.

Comment: Can you experiment with the values of `led0`...`led3` to find the addresses? They should be the same numbers you were using for `cnt`.

Comment: I have been doing experiments, the results are various , but not be able to trigger only one Led , its complicated for the person with non-electronics background, me.
i have managed to find what will the value of the variable value but that also not only triggering the particular pin. plus since few days my Serial monitor is not working. so cant predict the output same time.

Comment: Then I think we need a circuit diagram please.

Comment: I'd also suggest, if your serial monitor is not working, you're making things harder for yourself by working blind. Don't fall into a gumption trap https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Gumption_trap - get that fixed first.

Comment: hi i am using the WIFIClient , and the function client.print() , it gives me the values i want to see , but they are not helpful, is there any other way to just toggle the led on a particular pin of PCF8547. other all things i have written properly in my code , the GPIOs of ESP8266-12e i can toggle coz i have the pin no , but don't know how to access and toggle the pins on PCF8547. 
Serial monitor issue i will solve afterwards i have priority to solve this first. i have added circuit diagram in question too.

Comment: awesome. answer. solved my problem.

Comment: Glad I could help :-)